# Will the following code make my css deal with images in the optimum way?

Tags: css

In Appearance/Editor, the Stylesheet for my theme has in it the following code:

```
    #content img {
margin: 0;
max-width: 640px;
    }
    #content .attachment img {
max-width: 900px;
```

Does this mean that if I use the 'Add an image' button in WordPress, and then pick 'From url' to post an image in a blog post, that if the image at the url is bigger than the maximum width of my blog post, that it will not matter? -- That it won't result in the image taking longer than otherwise necessary to load on the users computer?

Comment: Also, next time please consider if the question is really WordPress related. If it is purely a CSS question than you will find better places to ask. See the FAQ for more and enjoy your time on WPSE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, the size of the source image still matters.**

**The rule only means that the image will not display wider then that.**
It is there mainly to prevent the large images from breaking the layout.

This will have no effect on the download time (browser is loading the original image anyway) and you are actually making browser do some little extra work to resize the image. Also different browsers will handle this task differently so be sure to check how your images look if they are being heavily browser-resized.

Further discussion and workarounds are out of the scope of this site.